# Passt image to view

Tags: laravel, view

I'm trying to insert an image into the view.
The name of the image is sent by the request.

```
  "image_file" => "58456eccaabfcaa9d29b2b0ee2a7a96d.JPG"
```

The image is in the folder public\images\upload
[image]

```
Article {#213 ▼
  ...
  #attributes: array:4 \[▼
    "id" => 38
    "title" => "fdhgi"
    "text" => "df"
    "image_file" => "58456eccaabfcaa9d29b2b0ee2a7a96d.JPG"
```

Try add image to view:

```
  <img src='images/upload/'{{$article->image_file}}>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few way to do so in Laravel, I am doing it in this way:

```
<img src="{{$app['url']->to('/')}}/public/images/upload/{{$article->image_file}}">
```